# In $\mathbb{Z_6}[x]$, factor each of the following into two polynomials of degree $1: x, x+2,x+3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This question is pretty confusing:

In $\mathbb{Z_6}[x]$, factor each of the following into two polynomials of degree $1: x, x+2,x+3$

so for example, do i have to find two polynomials that equal $x+2$?

I'm just confused about what the question is trying to say. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

What you want, for instance, is two linear factors $ax+b, cx+d$ such that 
$$(ax+b)(cx+d) = acx^2 + (ad+bc)x + bd \equiv x \pmod{6}$$
This is possible because $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ has zero divisors, most notably $2\cdot 3 = 6 \equiv 0$.